# Auth::attempt doesn't work from Postman

Tags: laravel, authentication, postman, phonegap

I know this question have been made many times, but none of that answers solved my problem, so here I go:

1. I use a clean installation of Laravel 5.4
2. I have Php 7.1.8
3. My table in DB is called usuario, and the two field to authenticate a request are "usuario" and "password"
4. config/auth.php has the next code in the provider section:

> ```
> 'providers' => [
>      'users' => [
>          'driver' => 'database',
>          'table' => 'usuario',
>      ],
> ],
> ```

5. The method login is this:

> ```
> public function login(Request $request)
> {
>     $user = $request->input('user');
>     $pass = sha1($request->input('pass'));
>     Log::debug("$user:$pass");
>     if(Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $user, 'password' => $pass])){
>         return "login";
>     }else{
>         return "no login";
>     }
> }
> ```

6. Inside Postman, I get this configuration
   [image]
7. The route in /routes/api.php is:

> Route::post('user/login', 'Usuario\Perfil@login');

That's all. The answer always is "no login". There is something I left?

For me is important to say that this project is not a 100% Laravel project, maybe 50%, because I only use Laravel as a back end. The client side will be a Javascript application from a mobile context using phonegap.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use https ?

Comment: No man, right now we don't have that feature

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your password hashing. Use Laravel's Hash façade: `Hash::make($password)` because `Auth::attempt` uses `Hash::check()` - and they both use same algorithms for hashing.